# Bubble Sorting an Array

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I'm writing a program to delete the lowest number from an array. I believe I'm almost to the point where I can solve the problem, however, I'm stuck on the last part (or so I think).

Example input and output:

Input: 1 2 3 4 5 7 10
Output: 1 2 3 4 5 7 10

Delete: 2 3 4 5 7 10
Delete: 3 4 5 7 10
Delete 4 5 7 10

And so on...

```
#include <iostream>
#include "queue.h"
#define SIZE 5
using namespace std;

class PriorityQueue
{
  int top, bottom;
  int numbers[SIZE];
public:
  PriorityQueue ()
  {
    top = bottom = -1;
  }

  void insert (int);
  void remove ();
  void display ();

  ~PriorityQueue ()
  {
  }
};

void PriorityQueue :: insert (int num)
{
  if (bottom == (SIZE -1) )
    cout << "Overflow queue is full" << endl;
  else if (bottom == -1)
    top = bottom = 0;
  else if (bottom < (SIZE -1) )
    bottom ++;
  numbers [bottom] = num;
}

void PriorityQueue :: remove ()
{
  for (int i=1; i <SIZE; i++)
  {
    for (int j=0; j < SIZE - i; j++)
    {
      if(top[j] > top[j +1])
      {
        SIZE temp = top[j];
        top[j] = top[j + 1];
        top[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  /*if ((top >= 0) && (top < SIZE))
    {
      cout << "\n Element removed = " << numbers[top];
      top++;
    }
  else
    cout << "Queue is empty";*/
}

void PriorityQueue :: display ()
{
  for (int i = top; i <= bottom; i++)
    cout << numbers [i] << ' ';
}

/*void bubbleSort(int numbers[], int n)
{
    for (int i=1; i <SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < SIZE - i; j++)
        {
            if(list[j] > list[j +1])
            {
                elemType temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j + 1];
                list[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}*/

int main ()
{
  PriorityQueue pq;
  int n, choose;
  while (1)
    {
      cout << " 1. Insert" <<endl;
      cout << " 2. Remove" <<endl;
      cout << " 3. Display" <<endl;
      cout << " 4. Exit " <<endl;
      cin >> choose;

      switch (choose)
    {
    case 1 : cout << "\n Enter element to push ";
      cin >> n;
      cout << endl;
      pq.insert (n);
      break;
    case 2 :
      pq.remove ();
      break;
    case 3 :
      pq.display ();
      cout <<endl;
      break;
    case 4 :
      return (0);
    }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

By sorting the array by the number's value

```
void PriorityQueue :: remove ()
{
  for (int i=1; i <SIZE; i++)
  {
    for (int j=0; j < SIZE - i; j++)
    {
      if(top[j] > top[j +1])
      {
        SIZE temp = top[j];
        top[j] = top[j + 1];
        top[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  /*if ((top >= 0) && (top < SIZE))
    {
      cout << "\n Element removed = " << numbers[top];
      top++;
    }
  else
    cout << "Queue is empty";*/
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to use a macro for a constant.

Comment: Changed SIZE temp to int temp.

Comment: top[j] ? top is a int.

Comment: elements should be moved to the top after sort and before removal, and remove should remove an object from the bottom by incrementing bottom, not by incrementing top

Comment: top[j] should be numbers[j]

Comment: either that or the bottom is at the top of the array and you are sorting things the wrong way

Comment: Julius, thank you. When code compiles, my brain begins to  work. I think that I can figure it out. The only problem I'm having now, is actually deleting the first number in the list.

Comment: top is useless and should always be == to SIZE. you should always insert one under bottom

Comment: then, you only need to increment bottom to remove an element

Comment: k anyways my code is better now

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE 5
class PriorityQueue
{
int numbers[SIZE];
int bottom;
public:
PriorityQueue():bottom(SIZE-1){};
void bubbleSort();
void insert(int num);
void remove();
void display();
};

void PriorityQueue :: bubbleSort () {
    //Sort
    for (int i = SIZE-1; i > bottom; --i) {
        for (int j = bottom ; j < SIZE - 2; j++) {
          if(numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1])
          {
            int temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
            numbers[j + 1] = temp;
          }
        }
    }
}

void PriorityQueue :: remove() {
    bubbleSort();
    if(bottom < SIZE-1) ++bottom;
}

void PriorityQueue :: insert (int num) {
    if (bottom < 0 ) {
        cout << "Queue is full" << endl;
        }
    else {
        --bottom;
        numbers [bottom] = num;
        cout<<"Insert. new value of bottom  index : " << bottom << "\n";
        }
}
void PriorityQueue::display(){
    if(bottom == SIZE-1){ cout<<"Nothing to display.\n";}
    else{
        for(int i = SIZE-2; i >= bottom; --i) {
            cout << numbers[i] << ((i!=bottom)?"::":"");
            }
    cout<<"\n";
}
}

int main(){
    PriorityQueue pq;
    pq.insert(2);
    pq.insert(5);
    pq.insert(1);
    pq.insert(3);
    pq.insert(9);
    pq.display();
    pq.bubbleSort();
    pq.display();
    pq.remove();
    pq.display();
    pq.remove();
    pq.remove();    
    pq.remove();    
    pq.remove();
    pq.display();
    pq.remove();
    pq.display();
    pq.insert(2);
    pq.display();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Insert. new value of bottom  index : 3
Insert. new value of bottom  index : 2
Insert. new value of bottom  index : 1
Insert. new value of bottom  index : 0
Insert. new value of bottom  index : -1
2::5::1::3::9
9::5::3::2::1
9::5::3::2
Nothing to display.
Nothing to display.
Insert. new value of bottom  index : 3
2
```

Comment: disclaimer: for inspiration only, not tested.

Comment: needs you to add `void bubbleSort()` to the class declaration, obviously

Comment: Hmm, I tried it out. The output is very odd...

Example: I inserted the numbers 4 2 3 5 1
I used the remove function and the output now displays 4 2 3 5 1 4916800

Comment: bottom should be initialized at SIZE-1

Comment: yup. changed a few things

Comment: insert should check if bottom == 0 to know if queue is full, not if it's == to SIZE -1. That would meen that it's empty

Comment: also.. bottom should be initialized at SIZE -1

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I might not reply right away, going on a coffee break. Thanks for your help thus far! I truly appreciate it.

Comment: You did waste my time sir, I'm learning a wealth of information due to your help!

Comment: Sorry DIDN'T waste my time.

Comment: ahah. glad I can help!

Comment: Hmm, tried your code from codepad; I'm showing a completely different output from yours. I'm getting the 3 2 1 0 -1 then segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you Julius! I think I have it from here. I'll post the modified code once I have it working 100% to my liking.